# Is it necessary to synchronize read to a variable?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am going through [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). Can some explain me the following doubts I am having in the code in Listing 2.8 which is shown below:-

```
@ThreadSafe
public class CachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger lastNumber;
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long hits;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long cacheHits;
    public synchronized long getHits() { return hits; }
    public synchronized double getCacheHitRatio() {
        return (double) cacheHits / (double) hits;
    }
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = null;
        synchronized (this) {
            ++hits;
            if (i.equals(lastNumber)) {
                ++cacheHits;
                factors = lastFactors.clone();
            }
        }
        if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            synchronized (this)  {
                lastNumber = i;
                lastFactors = factors.clone();
            }
}
        encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
    }
}
```

1. Is the `getCacheHitRatio` method necessary to be synchronized as the update to `cacheHits` and `hits` are from synchronized block and `getCacheHitRatio` is just reading the values?
2. Why `clone` has been used in `lastFactors` and `factors`? Can't I just use `factors=lastFactors`? This has not been explained in the chapter.

Comment: consider making the variables `volatile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The `synchronized` in the writing side only guarantees that

1.1 When entering the code block, all the previous operations before the `synchronized` are done and written to main memory.

1.2 All the variables operated in the block have their value directly from main memory (i.e. all cache lines are refreshed).

1.3 At the end of the block, the altered variables are written into the main memory before quitting the block.

So when you read from another thread, you need `synchronized` to make sure it reads the latest value from the main memory, not from the thread cached value (i.e. the CPU cache line are successfully refreshed before used).

2) I don't know what's factors but I guess it's a shared object. If so and assignment operator in Java is just pointer assignment i.e. you still pointing to the same factors object; thus operating on it (read and write) still need synchronization.

Comment: Regd #2 `factor` is just a local variable declared inside `service()`. So is there a need to use `clone()` here?

Comment: On reading the code I suppose it's an object (primitives don't have `clone()` anyway); so yeah you still subject to the refreshing problem for this object unless you copy it's entire content - exactly what the `clone()` does here.

Comment: There is a more important reason why `getCacheHitRatio()` needs to be `synchronized`:  It's not atomic!  If it were not synchronized, then it would be possible for it to calculate a ratio from a `hits` value and a `cacheHits` that don't "go together".  In other words, it could return a value that never was the actual ratio.  That might not seem important in _this_ application, but the same mistake could be disastrous in some other application.